# Dimension of fibers of finite type morphism between irreducible varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am having trouble understanding the reduction to the affine case in the proof of Theorem 11.4.1 in Vakil (found here: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf). The theorem says that:

> If $\pi \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a finite type morphism of irreducible $k$-varieties, with $\dim(X) = n$ and $\dim(Y) = m$, then there exists some nonempty open set $U \subseteq Y$ such that for each $q \in U$, the fiber over $q$ is either empty or has pure dimension $n - m$.

We may assume that $Y$ is affine. Then, the book states that:

> We may also assume that $X$ is affine, say $Spec A$. (Reason: cover $X$ with a finite number of affine open subsets $X_1, \dots, X_a$, and take the intersection of the $U$’s for each of the $\pi |_{X_i}$.)

Why is this statement true? In particular, for $q \in Y$, if $\dim(\pi^{-1}(q) \cap X_i)$ is either empty or pure dimension $\dim(X_i) - m$ for all $i$, then why is either $\pi^{-1}(q)$ empty or is pure dimensional with $\dim(\pi^{-1}(q)) = n - m$?

Comment: If $F = \cup_i F_i$ and each of the $F_i$ have dimension $d_i \in \{0, n-m\}$ then $\dim(F) \in \{0, n-m\}$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet, this would imply that $\dim(\pi^{-1}(q)) \leq n - m$, right? How can we see equality, and how can we see that the fiber has pure dimension?

Comment: I meant $-1$ instead of $0$, sorry. I wrote an answer.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I think it is possible that $\dim X_i < \dim X$ in this case! So then the dimension of $\pi^{-1}(q) \cap X_i < n - m$.

Comment: Sure, it can happens, but it's not a problem or a contradiction.

Comment: I think your answer is not enough to prove this, because it is possible that $X_1$ is the only affine chart with $\dim(X_1) = n$ and $X_1 \cap \pi^{-1}(q) = \emptyset$. Then in your notation, we would have that $F = \cup F_i$ with $\dim F_i < d$ for all $i$.

Comment: I don't understand your counter-example. If $X_i$ is open in $X$ then $\dim X_i = \dim X$ for all $i$. Right ? So $\dim X_i \cap \pi^{-1}(q)$ would be $n$ or $-1$ by hypothesis since $X_i$ is affine, and you are reduced to the lemma I wrote in the answer. I am missing something ?

Comment: It is not true generally that if $X_i$ is open in $X$, then $\dim X_i = \dim X$. Take for example the local Noetherian scheme $X = Spec(\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)})$, which has dimension 2. Consider the open subset $U = X \setminus \{0,0\}$. $U$ has dimension 1.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about this, thanks for the explanation and sorry for my useless comments.

Comment: When $X$ is a variety you do have $\dim X_i = \dim X$ if $X_i$ is a (non-empty) open in $X$!

Comment: @loch Thank you! That explains it :)